# Memory leaks in UIView class

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have created customize UIView with following code .....it's running with no issue....but when i check for Memory leaks...it shows leaks at point where i have made comment ...this is subclass of Uiview.
Please help me...

```
-(id) initWithLabel:(NSString*)labelName{

self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
    self.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
/*memory leaks 28.6% */ [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255 green:51.0/255 blue:51.0/255 alpha:1]];
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(86, 168, 160, 77)];
    [self setAlpha:1];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 28, 75, 21)];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor  clearColor]];
    [label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]];//memory leak 57%
    [label setText:labelName];
    [label setOpaque:NO];//memory leak
    [self addSubview:label];
    [label release];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(108, 22, 37, 37)];
    [activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [activityIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [activityIndicator setHidesWhenStopped:YES];
    [self addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator release];
}
return self;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  UIColor *myColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:51.0/255 green:51.0/255 blue:51.0/255 alpha:1];

  [self setBackgroundColor:myColor];

  [myColor release];
```

Hey man that is not memory leaks. that is autoreleased objects.so dont worry about them.apple wont reject urs.the condition is if u use alloc,init,new or retain then only u have responsibility to release.so leave it.otherwise do like above by alloc and init then release it .that'st it

Comment: AppleVijay:thanx for answer...now memory is not leaking at first point  but it still shows leaks at next two  points ie at font

Comment: Hey man that is not memory leaks. that is autoreleased objects.so dont worry about them.apple wont reject urs.the condition is if u use alloc,init,new or retain then only u have responsibility to release.so leave it.otherwise do like above by alloc and init then release it .that'st it

Comment: Any ideas why the profiling shows autoreleased objects as memory leaks ?